# ImportError: No module named _view using pygame2exe

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe, importerror

I am trying to distribute my game that was made using pygame.

I have been through what seems like hundreds of stackoverflow questions and online forums on a wild goose chase to finally come to using pygame2exe and getting so close but getting an ImportError.

For the other people who have asked this question, they seemed to have added `import pygame._view` to the top of their main script. I have done this but to no avail has it worked :(.

I would really like to solve my problem but I have no idea where to go from here. Could anyone help me to fix this problem?

-Thanks in advance, Landry.

Comment: Can you show us your code and full error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have shadowed real `pygame` package with your own one.
If yes - rename your package to avoid that `ImportError`.

See more info on  [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap) article.

Comment: Yes, some of my own packages are named the same as some python modules! I bet that would solve my problem. I have already moved most of my python things to my E-drive and I plan to dabble more with turning my python scripts to exes in the near future. I will definitely remember this when the time comes!